# Integrating Zennaware's Cornerstone with Coda and Xcode

Tags: xcode, svn, dreamweaver, cornerstone

I use the authoring tools Adobe's Dreamweaver, Coda and Xcode on the Mac with the awesome Subversion client Cornerstone from Zennaware. Anyone have any tips on how to integrate Cornerstone with these tools? Some tips on how to do initial imports and what global ignores to use would be a good start!

I am kinda new to version control and Cornerstone has made life much easier but I could do with some 'getting started' tips for my specific case.